# General purpose loop in Python Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I'm using the Python Bottle framework. How to perform some action every 10 seconds inside the Bottle main loop? i.e. where to call `worker_loop()` in the following code?

```
import time
from bottle import route, run, template, view, request

@route('/')
@view('test.html')
def index():
    context = {'request': request}
    return (context)

def worker_loop():
    work_on_the_db_each_10_seconds()
    time.sleep(10)

run(host='localhost', port=9000, debug=True)
```

Comment: maybe use `threading` and `while True` loop to run it all the time. You can use also use [shed](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sched.html) (or eventually `Celery`).

Comment: @furas I first wanted to use a new thread but I thought maybe `bottle` has a sleeping loop built-in that I could use.

Comment: it is not standard job for web frameworks (and web servers) so other frameworks use external programs like `Celery` (in Flask and Django). In Linux you can use even system program `cron` to run script periodically - but it can run every 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [schedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) , and a separate Thread to work on pending jobs.  You can find exmaple code [here](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/FAQ.rst).
If you plan to use something relaying on threads and using uwsgi or similar you should always be sure to enable threads in your configuration.

Comment: Please provide some code even though you link to example, so OP can get a feel for your answer.

Comment: Thanks in advance if you can add code example @ScR4tCh.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this the exact problem gevent solves?  Bottle has an adapter already that launches gevent if you have the module downloaded.

https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html

UPDATED example:

```
from gevent import monkey, spawn as gspawn, sleep as gsleep
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import time
from bottle import route, run, template, view, request
import bottle

@route('/')
@view('test.html')
def index():
    context = {'request': request}
    return (context)

def worker_loop():
    work_on_the_db_each_10_seconds()
    gsleep(10)

gspawn(worker_loop)

app = bottle.app()
WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 9000), app).serve_forever()
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal code example of how gevent can solve this?

Comment: This will allow an async thread to run every 10 seconds without blocking your bottle app.